# How exactly do i use beginInsertRows()?

Tags: c++, qt

When i use this function like below.

```
beginInsertRows()

beginInsertRows: identifier not found
```

I'm new to c++. How do i call this function? I'm including QtSql.
Should i include something special?

**EDIT**:
I've searched for solutions and all of them point to using this function 
as i posted. But i'm getting this error.

```
    this->sqlModel2 = new QSqlQueryModel();
    sqlTableModel = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    sqlTableModel->setTable("mytable");
    sqlTableModel->select();

    qDebug()<< sqlTableModel->lastError().text();

    ui->listView->setModel(sqlTableModel);
    ui->listView->setModelColumn(1);



            QString name;
            name= " My name";
            QSqlQuery qryInsert;
            QString mInsert "INSERT INTO mytable (:name) VALUES (:name)";

            qryInsert.prepare(mInsert);

            qryInsert.bindValue(":name",name);
            beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(),0,1) ;
            if(qryInsert.exec()){
                      qDebug()<<"Inserted";
                      result = "inserted";


                  }else{
                      qDebug()<<"Error inserting = "<<qry.lastError().text();
                  }
             endInsertRows();
```

Comment: You will have to post much more of your code than that.

Comment: `beginInsertRows()` is a (protected) member function of `QAbstractItemModel`. Can you show a bit more code?

Comment: Little more context please - Which class? Do you inherit from some ItemModel?, etc.

Comment: @Johny its in the QMainWindow class.

Comment: So that is your problem - as I wrote in my answer you can call the method only in class inheriting from `QAbstractItemModel`. `QMainWindow` just don't implement this. Read the documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`beginInsertRows()` is method of `QAbstractItemModel` and it is protected. So you can call it only when you subclass `QAbstractItemModel` inside of its methods. More info [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html).